# redis installation using conda not working ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'redis'

Tags: python, redis, installation, conda

As my pip proxy does not work and I had to use conda to install redis.
After I successfully installed redis using conda. in python shell mode, I tried to import redis, and got the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis'

Running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago) and anaconda 3, python 3.7.1

Any ideas how I can install redis correctly without using pip?

Comment: since i could not use pip, I ended up install it manually by downloading the source files.

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/redis-py, https://anaconda.org/anaconda/redis-py

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This boils down to the fact that while conda's primary use is to support Python workflows, it's not a Python package manager, but a package manager that can package and distribute software built on any stack.

In particular, the [redis](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/redis) package from the Anaconda channel is *not* the Python interface that you get through `pip install redis`. Rather it's Redis proper; the actual server software.

In the Anaconda channel, the Python interface is called [redis-py](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/redis-py), so if you already have Redis running somehow, you would just grab that one through

```
conda install redis-py
```